# Failed to build gem native extension on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, capistrano

I got a strengh error, when ever i try to deploy my app with capistrano it stops at bundle install, it says that :

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb

Gem files will remain installed in 

/home/deployer/apps/Myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3

Results logged to /home/deployer/apps/Myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/ext/gem_make.out

Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I tried to install it from server : gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3', it succeeds but when i re-deploy from local it fails.

nb : I was getting the same error with nokogiri, it annoyed me so i dropped it.

What's the solution ?

**Edited**

Is it because my ruby version is not compatible with those gems ?
I found on Eventmachine site : EventMachine supports Ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.2
and on nokogiri site : REQUIREMENTS: ruby 1.8 or 1.9

**Edited**

Here is my gem environment:

```
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.1.11
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-11-22 patchlevel 353) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/deployer/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353
     - /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin
     - /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin
     - /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin
```

Comment: Can you post the logged errors in the location specified?

Comment: The error log contains one line : 
/home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb

Comment: Is not a compatibility issue, eventmachine 1.0.3 is perfectly compatible with ruby-2.0.0-p353

Comment: Could you create 2 files in your porject's dir with this content? `$ vim .ruby-version` with `2.0.0` and `$ vim .ruby-gemset` with `myprojectgemset` and deploy again. It looks like you have some binaries pointing to the wrong ruby version.

Comment: I created .ruby-version with 2.0.0 and .ruby-gemset with holo (the name of my project). but it fails again

Comment: what do you think if i do a bundle install with --verbose ?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade rvm and run rvm requirements (on the target prod server)

```
$ rvm get head
$ rvm reload
$ rvm requirements
```

Comment: Did you run that on your target server right? If not keep reading: I see you tried installing eventmachine manually and succeeded. Could you try this: ssh into the target server and run `$ rvm use system` then try to install the gem eventmachine like you did before. If it fails then capistrano is picking the wrong ruby version on deployment. Take a look at my comment for adding a .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset to your project.

Comment: I tried to set rvm system as you said, still getting the same error, i changed also rvm_type in deploy.rb from user to system (set :rvm_type, :user) , but getting : ERROR: RVM Ruby not used, run `rvm use ruby` first.